# updating dates in mongodb with angularJS and input type="date"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, date

I have a MongoDb *student* collection. A student can have a number of courses (opl) which contains start- and enddates. 
I use Mongoose to create a REST interface in server.js:

```
//adres Schema
var adresSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    gemeente: String,
    post: Number,
    straat: String
})
//opl Schema
var oplSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    oplcode: Number,
    geslaagd: Boolean,
    startdatum: Date,
    einddatum: Date,
})

//Studenten Schema
var studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        voornaam: String,
        familienaam: String,
        email: String,
        adres:  adresSchema,
        foto: String,
        ikl: Number,
        opl: [oplSchema],
        rijksreg: String,
        gender: String,
        tel: [String]
    }, {collection:"studenten"})
```

to query for a student I use this Route on the Model:

```
/GET /api/studenten/:id  1 enkele student by id
apiRouter.get('/studenten/:id', function(req, res) {

    return studentModel.findById(req.params.id,function(err, student) {
        if (!err) {

            res.send(student);// 1 student
        }
        else {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    })
```

})

My problem is how to use Angular and the HTML5 input type="date" which requires a Date() object to show the *startdatum* and *einddatum* dates?
I use an Angular service like this to create the $scope:

```
.factory('studentService',['$resource', function($resource){
        var urlBase = "api/studenten";
        var studentResource = $resource(
            urlBase + '/:_id',
            {_id: '@_id'},
            {update: {method:'PUT'}
            }
        )
        return studentResource;
    }])
```

Then in the  student Edit controller I fill the $scope with the service:

```
 .controller('StudentEditCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'studentService', 'opleidingService','$location',
        function ($scope, $routeParams, studentService, opleidingService, $location) {

            //update student and his courses (opl)

            $scope.subtitel         = "Update student";
            $scope.student          = studentService.get({}, {'_id': $routeParams._id}); 

            //save
            $scope.save = function (student) {

                if ($scope.student._id) {
                    //update

                    console.log("updating student " + student.familienaam);
                    studentService.update({_id: $scope.student._id}, $scope.student);
                }
                else {
                      //new student                 
                    $scope.student.$save();
                }
                $location.path('/studenten');
            }
```

//more methods, some things left out

How can I use my *$scope.student.opl.startdatum* dateStrings (ISODates) to create a Date object to be used in

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="opl.startdatum "  />
```

such that its value is an ISO String and I can use it to update the courses dates.
I have been reading myself silly, but nowhere does anyone show how to convert the Mongoose ISOString to a Date object... all examples start with a new Date() object they create themselves.
The $scope.student.opl doesn't allow me to change the dates to a Date Object. I don't seem to be able to add a field to it to. Filters don't work. 
Actually this below displays the date correctly, but it throws up a whole number of errors and the update value is empty:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="opl.einddatum" value="{{opl.einddatum | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" />
```

Using a method like

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" ng-model="makeDate(opl.startdatum) "  />
```

doesn't work either. I looked at angular-ui-bootstrap, but here it is the same: you need a Date object.

I am probably missing a crucial strategic point here, but I would appreciate some help to show me my mistake, thanks,

Jan

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the ISO string to date object by below format,

> var date=new Date('2015-11-13T06:16:11.399Z')

In your case it will be like,

> $scope.student.opl.startdatum = new Date($scope.student.opl.startdatum);

Comment: Hi Kumar,this does'nt work since my service returns a $resource and that is asynchronous: I can't directly edit $scope.student.
so my question boils down to: how can I edit/change/add to an asynchronous resource before (or after) I i fill a scope with it?